# Two part CCK field

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

Is there a way to add one CCK field which consists of two separate fields, e.g. Author(s), having first name and last name on separate fields?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Show answer: not easily.

Long answer: yes, but with a bit of php trickery.

Look at this doc [here](http://drupal.org/node/229893), specifically, the lower "join" part will get you on the right track, but its specifically for 5.x. If you are working on 7.x this would be quite a bit different.

Comment: I'm using Drupal 6, but I'll take a look at that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CCK 3.x for Drupal 6, which contains a sub-module called Multigroup, which allows you to take groups of fields (first name, last name for example), and repeat those groupings. However, before using this version of the module, note that it does not have an officially supported release, and [its future is a bit uncertain](http://drupal.org/node/690140).

Comment: Good tips, but I'd rather use stable (not that my own code is that stable) versions. This looks a bit more complex to implement than what I thought.

Comment: I also mis-read your question. I assumed you wanted multiple value groupings. To simply make them look like one, you should go with the 2 fields approach mentioned by xtfer, and use a bit of CSS on the form to get them looking like you want. Anywhere you are displaying them, you can either use the computed field, or Views will support joining the values.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other suggestions, you could try Flexifield, or just have two different fields.

To make two fields end up looking like one...

1. display them together later on using inline fields or by altering the template
2. use Actions to join the two values together and save them to a different field, or
3. use Computed Field to write them to another field on node save

Content Multigroup in CCK3 currently has no upgrade path to Drupal 7 and its interface is a bit clunky if you aren't planning on having a multi-value, multipart field.